# Question wise answer type chat interface between multiple users at the same time

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, codeigniter-3

I have an application that has a requirement like teacher and student question answer chat. There may be 1 to many relation simultaneously. So, can anybody suggest me laraval broadcasting would be sufficient to achieve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Laravel Websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) package.

Take a look at this Chat example: https://github.com/qirolab/Laravel-WebSockets-Chat-Example.

Part from the tutorial:

**Controller**

```php
public function fetchMessages()
{
    return Message::with('user')->get();
}

public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    $message = auth()->user()->messages()->create([
        'message' => $request->message
    ]);
    broadcast(new MessageSent($message->load('user')))->toOthers();
    return ['status' => 'success'];
}
```

**JS**

```js
function fetchMessages() {
    axios.get('messages').then(response => {
        this.messages = response.data;
    })
}
function sendMessage() {
    this.messages.push({
        user: this.user,
        message: this.newMessage
    });
    axios.post('messages', {message: this.newMessage});
    this.newMessage = '';
}
```